# How to add condition to differentiate between dashed and solid focus square?

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit

I am working on one AR application. It includes focus square( Dashed and Solid focus) which gives user hint about the status of ARkit object tracking.

Currently " add object(+)" is coming for dashed focus square. I don't want it when dashed focus square is present. It should only be active or enabled for solid 
focus square. 
Can anyone tell me how to differentiate between dashed and solid focus square? 
I am attaching images for better understanding of the situation.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't actually included any code for your `FocusSquare`, it's quite hard to help you.

However, taking a wild guess, I am assuming you are using the `Apple Example Focus Square` sample...

If this is the case, then if you look at the code you will see that there is a `private var` called `isOpen` around line 83:

```
private var isOpen = false
```

If you change this to a `public var`:

```
public var isOpen = false
```

You can run a check in the `updateAtTime` callback in the `ARSCNViewDelegateMethod` e.g:

```
 func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {

        if focusSquare.isOpen{

            print("Focus Square Is Open")

        }else{

            print("Focus Square Is Closed")
        }

}
```

And handle it as you wish.

This is an easy fix, but I suggest you use this as a basis to make a more *solid* solution.

Hope this points you in the right direction...

In addition when the `FocusSquare` is closed then it means a `plane` has been detected, which again provides another way to handle the functionality.